# how to destroy exact session

Tags: php, session

If i've `$_SESSION["something"]` and `$_SESSION["else"]`
by using `session_destroy()` it will destroy both.

but what if i want only to destroy exact session which is `$_SESSION["something"]` and keeps `$_SESSION["else"]` active.

Comment: You cant have multiple sessions. Those are variables/entries/objects/whatever in your session.

Comment: `session_destroy()` does NOT unset your $_SESSION values. As is clearly mentioned in the manual. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `unset($_SESSION['something'])`.

Bear in mind that these aren't separate sessions, they're entries in the same session id.  You only have one active session.

Answer (score 1):

$_SESSION is like a normal array.....so use unset to clear whatever you want ...as suggested in previous answer.....

Answer (score 0):

unset( $_SESSION['variable'] );

The above will not work with register_globals turned on (will only
work outside of a function).

$variable = $_SESSION['variable'];
unset( $_SESSION['variable'], $variable );

The above will work with register_globals on & inside a function